# mysql; iterate through a table and calculate avgerage price

Tags: mysql, sum, iteration

I have the following query from a podetail table where I calculate the average price for "one" unique item at a time. I need to create a list of "avgUnitCost".Is there a way to use this existing query in a subquery to produce the list of avgUnitCost?

```
SELECT  items.`itemName`,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS qtyRcvd,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) AS totalUnitCost,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) / SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS avgUnitCost

FROM podetails, items, purchaseorders
WHERE purchaseorders.`poID` = podetails.`poID`
  AND podetails.`itemID` = items.`itemID`
  AND podetails.`itemID` = 3;>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` statement here. Not sure on which column exactly but by assumption you should group by `items.itemName` like

```
SELECT  items.`itemName`,
    SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS qtyRcvd,

    SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) AS totalUnitCost,

    SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) / SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS avgUnitCost

FROM podetails JOIN purchaseorders

ON
    purchaseorders.`poID` = podetails.`poID`
JOIN items

ON
    podetails.`itemID` = items.`itemID`

WHERE
    podetails.`itemID` = 3

GROUP BY items.`itemName`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `avgUnitCost` for the items which all are present in `purchaseorders` table, below query may help you

```
SELECT  items.`itemName`,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS qtyRcvd,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) AS totalUnitCost,
        SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived` * podetails.`unitCost`) / SUM(podetails.`qtyReceived`) AS avgUnitCost

FROM podetails, items, purchaseorders
WHERE purchaseorders.`poID` = podetails.`poID`
  AND podetails.`itemID` = items.`itemID`
  GROUP BY items.`itemID`;
```

This small change of using `GROUP BY` may give you the result as expected